# Google Analytics tracking within Lightbox image gallery

Tags: google-analytics, lightbox

I found some topics which might have been related to my issue, but I wasn't 100% sure.

I want to setup Events tracking (Google Analytics) so that I know which photos from a Lightbox image gallery attract the most attention.

I used this:

```
a rel="lightbox[portrait]" href="images/image-14.jpg" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Image', 'Open Image', '14' ]);"><img src="images/thumb-14.jpg"></a>
```

But of course, if the visitor then uses the left/right arrows to navigate, I only know which photo was the initial click.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your existing setup answers your question.
Left/right arrow navigation within the lightbox doesn't really tell you which photos a given user found interesting as they are no longer selecting.

In saying that, what it is though is a measure of engagement. What you could do is keep count of how many transitions + initial selections a user made and push that as a custom variable or a custom metric (in case of GA Universal) which would then allow you to set a threshold to qualify visitors.